Google Earth Engine in QGIS pugin update - is it related to Quickmap services?
I opened my Qgis project and I got that window (screenshot), the link in the window is this one https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/transition_to_cloud_projects
I don't understand the limits of accepting this new configuration so I would like to say no and just remove the GEE plugin. But if I use the Quickmap services plugin, is it related in some way to GEE?


The QMS plugin only uses open data services (available without authentication) and is not associated with GEE plugin . Therefore you can freely uninstall the GEE plugin, it will not affect the QMS plugin.
